# Sum total of all text box value in a row using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want to sum all the text box value in a html table row using jQuery.
here is the table:

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
      <th>sl</th>
      <th>TA</th>
      <th>DA</th>
      <th>HA</th>
      <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td><td>
      <input id="expenses_sum"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td><td>
      <input id="expenses_sum"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td><td>
      <input id="expenses_sum"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the jQuery function to add the value of all text box of class expenses and display the result in a text box of id expenses_sum.

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
  $(".expenses").each(function() {    
    $(this).keyup(function() {     
      calculateSum();
    });
  });
});    

function calculateSum() {    
  var sum = 0;        
  $(".expenses").each(function() {          
    if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
      sum += parseFloat(this.value);
    }    
  });

  $("#expenses_sum").val(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

how to use this function for each row.

Comment: why does this has a php tag ?

Comment: And most important `expenses_sum`! (IDs must be unique)

Answer (score 6):

Firstly you have repeated the same `id` when they should be unique which means your HTML is invalid. You should use a common class instead.

To make this work you need to restrict the `.expenses` selector to only find the elements within the same row as the input which was changed. To do that you can use `closest()` to get the nearest parent `tr`, then `find()` to get all the inputs.

Also note there are several logic improvements you can make here:

- remove the `each()` loop to add the event handler
- providing the reference of `calculateSum` to the event handler so you can use the `this` keyword to traverse the DOM
- provide a default value of `0` to the value to simplify the sum logic
- hook to the `change` event as well as `keyup` for when users paste data in to the field. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".expenses").on('keyup change', calculateSum);
});

function calculateSum() {
  var $input = $(this);
  var $row = $input.closest('tr');
  var sum = 0;

  $row.find(".expenses").each(function() {
    sum += parseFloat(this.value) || 0;
  });

  $row.find(".expenses_sum").val(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>sl</th>
    <th>TA</th>
    <th>DA</th>
    <th>HA</th>
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td><input class="expenses"></td>
    <td><input class="expenses"></td>
    <td><input class="expenses"></td>
    <td><input class="expenses_sum"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td><input class="expenses"></td>
    <td><input class="expenses"></td>
    <td><input class="expenses"></td>
    <td><input class="expenses_sum"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td><input class="expenses"></td>
    <td><input class="expenses"></td>
    <td><input class="expenses"></td>
    <td><input class="expenses_sum"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use like this

```
$(document).on('keyup change','input.expenses',function(){

  $expenses = $(this).parents('tr').find('.expenses');
  $expenseTotal = $(this).parents('tr').find('#expenses_sum');
  $expenseTotal.val('0');
  $.each($expenses,function(index,object){      
    if($(object).val()!='')
    {
       $expenseTotal.val(parseInt($expenseTotal.val())+parseInt($(object).val()));
    }
  });
});
```

see demo at - https://jsfiddle.net/Vesharj/zLg3pyq4/

Answer (score 1):

Here is the right way to do this.

```
    <table border="1">
  <tr>
      <th>sl</th>
      <th>TA</th>
      <th>DA</th>
      <th>HA</th>
      <th>Total</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td><td>
      <input class="expenses_sum"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td><td>
      <input class="expenses_sum"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td>
      <td><input class="expenses"></td><td>
      <input class="expenses_sum"></td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

And js :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".expenses").each(function() {

      $(this).keyup(function(){
            sum($(this).parents("tr"));
      });
    });
});
function sum(parent){
    var sum = 0;
    $(parent).find(".expenses").each(function(){
        if(!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length!=0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });
    $(parent).find(".expenses_sum").val(sum.toFixed(2));
}
```

Hope, it helps

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!